# Infragistics Windows Forms Controls Localization

Tags: winforms, localization, infragistics

I'm working on WinForms app localization. For UI elements I have .resx files in which I'm writing localized strings. The problem is with Infragistics controls. I can't get for example items names in toolbars to which I can refer in .resx file. I'm looking for solution for some time, but unsuccessfully. Do anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Please post some code, maybe read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To localize Infragistics for Windows Forms controls you may use their Resource Strings. Check [here](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/win-customizing-assembly-resource-strings) how to apply customized strings, and [here](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wintoolbarsmanager-resource-strings) for all the UltraToolbarsManager resource strings.